# How do I set maxReceivedMessageSize on Self Hosted WCF Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, wcf

I have an issue where I am giving my Self Hosted WCF service more data than it can handle. I have set the maxReceivedMessageSize on my client, but in this case the client is passing the data to the server, so I need to set MaxReceivedMessageSize on the server. I am not using any config files, and I am not sure how to get it set within my current config...

**Client:**

```
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
       <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Iplutocomm"
                receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxReceivedMessageSize ="210242880">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

**Self Hosted Service**

```
Dim myServiceAddress As New Uri("http://" & LocalIpAddress & ":" & tcp_port & "/" & servicename)

myservicehost = New ServiceHost(GetType(plutocomm), myServiceAddress)

'Enable metadata publishing

Dim smb As New ServiceMetadataBehavior()
smb.HttpGetEnabled = True
smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15
myservicehost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb)

myservicehost.Open()
```

**New Changes / Update**

Doing it like this, will that override the default basichhtp binding that I assume the framework setup because I did not initially specifically create a binding?

I short, will the below code, running on my service, allow my current client config to "plug in" to the new binding? Will I now still have only one binding a sbefore, but my created one, replacing the default one?

```
    Dim myServiceAddress As New Uri("http://" & LocalIpAddress & ":" & tcp_port & "/" & servicename)

    myservicehost = New ServiceHost(GetType(plutocomm), myServiceAddress)


    '*******NEW CHANGES

    Dim BasicBinding As New BasicHttpBinding
    BasicBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647

    myservicehost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(plutocomm), BasicBinding, myServiceAddress)

    '/*******NEW CHANGES

    ' Enable metadata publishing.
    Dim smb As New ServiceMetadataBehavior()
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = True
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15
    myservicehost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb)

    myservicehost.Open()
```

Comment: Out of interest, why can't you just use a service config file?

Comment: No specific reason. This is a long standing app that I implemented as per above, working on examples of self hosting. I won't want to change the concept too much now, as its been bulletproof thus far, and currently in a production environment.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397532/how-to-override-webservicehostfactory-maxreceivedmessagesize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), passing in the binding of your choice.

In your case this is the basicHttpBinding with maxReceivedMessageSize set.

This method has 5 overloads so you can just choose the one you want.

Comment: Yes that will work, however, a nicer solution in my opnion would be to make this config driven. Then you don't need to worry about if this changes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dim myBinding As New BasicHttpBinding() With { _
    Key .MaxReceivedMessageSize = 210242880 _
}
myservicehost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(plutocomm), myBinding, myServiceAddress)
```

Update:

Your bindings need to be "Coherent", they don't need to be the same.(if your client config have a 60 seconds timeout, a server with 30 seconds timeout would work but would be incoherent, same goes with message Size)